# Checkbox submits only one checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have a form with multiple checkboxes, say A, B, C, D. Sometimes i will want the user to select more than one checkboxes, say B and C. When I do that I will see only the last value 'C' in the database. How will I modify my codes below to have BC submitted to the database?

**FORM**

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="check_trash.php">
<input type="text" name="afam" require />

A<input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="A">  
B<input type="checkbox" name="get_value[]" value="B">  
C<input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="C">  
D<input type="checkbox" name="get_value[]" value="D">

<button id="subm" name="upload" style="color:#fff; padding:5px 66px" class="btn btn-success" ><b>Save</b></button>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#subm").click( function() {

$.post( $("#myform").attr("action"), $("#myform").serialize(), function(info){ $("#result").html(info); } );
clearInput();
});

$("#myform").submit( function() {
    return false;
});

function clearInput() {
$('#myform').each(function(){
this.reset();
});    
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_POST["get_value"])){
foreach($_POST["get_value"] as $checkbox){
}
$name = $_POST['myname'];
$insert_query = "insert into trash (checkbox,name) values ('$checkbox','$name')";

$run_query = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query);
if($run_query){
    echo "Submitted successfully";
}
else {
    echo "failed";
}
}

else{
echo "<script>alert('Please select at least one option!')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` for `$_POST["get_value"]`

Comment: Do you mean I should replace $_POST["get_value"] with var_dump ?

Comment: No, just add `var_dump($_POST)` in your php file before `if(!empty($_POST["get_value"])){`

Comment: I did this: var_dump($_POST);
if(!empty($_POST["get_value"])){ and it still submitted only one value and gave this error array(2) { ["afam"]=> string(6) "joseph" ["get_value"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(1) "B" } } Question set successfully

Comment: Add it to the question so it can be cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Use serilizeArray() method instead of serialize()

```
$.post( $("#myform").attr("action"),   $("#myform").serializeArray(), function(info){  $("#result").html(info); } );
```

Comment: Using serializeArray() does not submit more than one checkbox value

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST["get_value"]))
{
    $checkedOptions = '';
    foreach($_POST["get_value"] as $checkbox)
    {

        $checkedOptions .= $checkbox;

    }


    $name = $_POST['myname'];
    $insert_query = "insert into trash (checkbox,name) values ('$checkedOptions','$name')";

    $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query);
    if(!$run_query)
    {
        echo "Submitted successfully";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "failed";
    }
}

else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Please select at least one option!')</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This code inserts the multiple checked values into different table rows, giving them different IDs. That is, If I check A and B, 'A' will be given id 1, and 'B' given id 2 in the database table. I want them to appear as 'AB' having same ID.

Comment: Ok now check the new edit I think this is what you asked for, right ???

Comment: Worked like a charm. Exactly what i needed. Thank you very much. However I removed ! from if(!$run_query), if not it will echo failed even though it submits the correct values.

Comment: Thanks up vote my answer and accept it to close the topic

Comment: I have already up voted your answer, but how do I accept to close the topic?

Comment: I dont know iam new here :(

Comment: Just click on the tick and please accept the answer friend